# Filling parts of image with different colors from code behind in Asp.Net C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, css

i wish to add various colors depending upon the numbers coming from database into an image like below, I had a check with the D3.js, couldn't understand it better.

Rather than that I am trying to do it from the codebehind, can anyone please tell me how can i change the colors from codebehind at particular XY Coordinates of the image ?

how to also calculate XY coordinates ? Thanks in advance [image: map]

Comment: to be able to do this even remotely some time in your life time, the best way would be to break up the map into individual images. You could then use Image.SetPixel to color it. Though if it were me, id just break each section into multiple images of different colors then just load the image section_1_green for example

Comment: nope, need the map to be as it is, anyways thanks for your inputs

Comment: does it have to be multiple screen resolutions?

Comment: umm i wish it worked on ipad and mobiles but i understand that xy coordinates will also keep changing as per the device width, hence thinking if it works fine for desktop atleast